# Unity camera got stuck with a particular view in build file after importing objects from blender

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, virtual-reality

I attached a First-Person Camera Control script to Unity's camera for navigating in the scene. Then I imported an object from blender and placed it in the scene. When I clicked the play mode, everything works fine (i.e. navigating in the scene). But when I ran the app after build, I can't navigate and got stuck with a view to which I did not set the Unity's camera.

[image]

This is the view to which I got stuck but I did not set the Unity's camera to focus this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem is. In Blender, there will a default camera present in the scene.

[image]

And this camera was pointing to the view below -_-

[image]

I imported the object to unity without deleting this camera which caused the trouble. After deleting this camera, my problem was solved.